# Trying to get data of the row clicked of the table react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, onclick

I am new to react,and making app where I want to  get data of the row being clicked on a table,I don't whether this approach is good or not need suggestions

So far i have used onClick listener but when I click on a table , it gives me [object,object] in console.log(contract),I have also tried to to use loop to view data in it but it gives me [object,object],here's my below code:

```
    <table id="mytable" cellSpacing="0" width="100%">
         <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>CarName</th>
             <th>DriverName</th>
             <th>Date</th>
             <th>Pickup</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
          <tbody>

          {                                   
            this.state.contracts.map((contract,index)=>{
            return(
              <tr key={index}  data-item={contract} onClick={this.contractdetails}>
                            <td>{contract.car} </td>                                                       
                            <td>{contract.driver}</td>
                            <td>{contract.date}</td>
                            <td>{contract.pickup}</td>
              </tr>
                      )})

            }
          </tbody>
         </table>
```

**onClickfunction**

```
 contractdetails=(e)=>{
    const contract=e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-item');
    console.log(contract)
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify` while setting the `data-item`

```
<tr key={index}  data-item={JSON.stringify(contract)} onClick={this.contractdetails}>
```

And use `JSON.parse()` while accessing it.

```
contractdetails=(e)=>{
    const contract= JSON.parse(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-item'));
    console.log(contract)
};
```

A better way is to just set `index` as `data-index` and you can access it from the `state`

```
this.state.contracts.map((contract,index)=>{
            return(
              <tr key={index}  data-index={index} onClick={this.contractdetails}>
               ...
               ...

            }
```

You can access it like below

```
contractdetails=(e)=>{
    let index = +e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-index')
    console.log(this.state.contracts[index]);
};
```

Comment: @MUHAMMADNABEELL1F14BSCS0108 I have added a better approach make sure to check it. Setting data as `data-item` is useless because you already have all the data inside state. I don't prefer the first solution.

Comment: @MUHAMMADNABEELL1F14BSCS0108 Consider accepting the answer if you feel it helpful